# EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2672) error showing when calling ftp.storbinary method

Tags: python, ssl, ftplib

I have tried the following code an empty file is uploaded to the FTP server. The nlst and retrbinary methods worked fine without any issues. But for storbinary "ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2672)" error is showing when unwrap function is called in the ftplib.

```
class MyFTP_TLS(FTP_TLS):
    """Explicit FTPS, with shared TLS session"""
    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        conn, size = ftplib.FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
        if self._prot_p:
            conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
                                            server_hostname=self.host,
                                            session=self.sock.session)  # this is the fix
        return conn, size

# METHOD TO ESTABLISH CONNECTION
def connect():
    ftp = MyFTP_TLS()
    ftp.set_pasv(True)
    ftp.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
    ftp.debugging = 2

    ftp.connect(pac_hostname, pacific_ftp_port,timeout=100)
    ftp.auth()
    ftp.login(pac_username, pac_password)
    ftp.prot_p()
    return ftp
 
# ESTABLISH FTP CONNECTION
ftp = connect()

bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
bytes_buffer.write(b"Testing")
bytes_buffer.seek(0)
res = ftp.storbinary("STOR UNSYNCED_FILE_2.txt", bytes_buffer)
```

Comment: If some data connections work but this particular not it might be due to the action resulting in a server side error. Please make sure that you actually have the permissions to store the file at this location. Also make sure that the problem is actually in your code, i.e. that it works with other FTP clients. Also check server side error logs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your response. I have checked it again with my code. It seems like the file is transferring to the FTP even though the error is throwing. But, I am not clear why this error is showing when the file transfer is working fine. Anyway, my issue has been resolved.

Comment: If the file is transferring the issue is likely that the server is not doing the required SSL shutdown but simply closes the TCP connection. Some servers have such bugs, but this typically also happens with all data transfers, i.e. also listing and file retrieval and not only storing a file.

Comment: It seems like what you have said is correct. The error is thrown during SSL shutdown.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. What did you do fix this issue? File upload transfers fine but then throws SSL error: ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2702). I can upload fine with other clients.